# How to reduce the loading time of alternate stylesheets?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'am using jQuery theme switcher (with local storage). I have got 4 buttons. Onclick of each button, the respective theme loads.

But I have a problem here. Each time page loads, the default theme loads first and switches to the theme stored in local storage. How do I load the alternate stylesheet fast without default theme being shown?

```
        "<link id="styleswitch" href="#" rel="stylesheet" /> "
<ul class="nav collapse" style="">
    <li>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);"  data-toggle="load-css" data-uri="../../Styles/theme1.css" class="no-submenu">
            <div class="label  pull-right" style="background-color:#2980b9"><i class="fa fa-paint-brush"></i></div>
            <span class="item-text">&nbsp;Dodger Blue</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);"  data-toggle="load-css" data-uri="../../Styles/theme2.css" class="no-submenu">
            <div class="label  pull-right" style="background-color:#85668B"><i class="fa fa-paint-brush"></i></div>
            <span class="item-text">&nbsp;Medium Purple</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);"  data-toggle="load-css" data-uri="../../Styles/theme3.css" class="no-submenu">
            <div class="label  pull-right" style="background-color:#7EA53C"><i class="fa fa-paint-brush"></i></div>
            <span class="item-text">&nbsp;Olive Green</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);"  data-toggle="load-css" data-uri="../../Styles/theme4.css" class="no-submenu">
            <div class="label  pull-right" style="background-color:#6D90C5"><i class="fa fa-paint-brush"></i></div>
            <span class="item-text">&nbsp;Cornflower Blue</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);"  data-toggle="load-css" data-uri="../../Styles/theme5.css" class="no-submenu">
            <div class="label  pull-right" style="background-color:#1E5237"><i class="fa fa-paint-brush"></i></div>
            <span class="item-text">&nbsp;Default theme</span> <!--this is the default theme -->
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: i have already posted

Comment: you can add `disabled` attribute to the stylesheets that are not being used, this will disable styles from that file.

Comment: The title of this question is kinda misleading. Increasing the load time would mean you slow down the loading. Instead you want the exact opposite.

Comment: yeah. i'm sorry... i was in a hurry...yes i have corrected the title of my question

Answer (score 3):

This is a common 'flickering' issue, you also see with frameworks like AngularJS.

The solution is rather simple. You can hide the contents, until the initialization is done.

#### CSS

```
body {
  display: none; 
}
body.initialized {
  display: block;
}
```

#### JS

```
// Initialization like loading the stylesheet, then
document.body.classList.add('initialized');
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello You can add style sheet using Append or prepend methord of jQuery and you can add this using Delay() of JQuery so that, you can add this according to your timeline requirement

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

setTimeout(function(){ 
         $("head").append("<link href='css/sarbasishstyle.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>");
 }, 3000);
  
  
});
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title> Header is here </title>
    </head>
  
  <body>
    Hello
    </body>
 </html>
```

Hope this may help you, Because i have tried it and its working

You can remove css like that which is not required. You can do it by using ID attribute. Give Id to each stylesheet and check if it is exist in the html or not  then remove which are not require and add the which is essential .

Thanks . if you have any doubt then let me know